# Cucumber-jvm - Retrieving embedded image from TestCaseFinished event

Tags: java, cucumber, screenshot

I have a cucumber plugin where I post my test case results to TestRail using the TestCaseFinished event. It works so far, but on failed steps, I use the scenario.embed method to add a screenshot of the failed step. The TestCaseFinished event does not contain this (or the scenario.write method)

Is there any way to retrieve this information using a cucumber plugin? I considered, during the @After hook, when taking the screenshot, to save the image temporarily in the target directory but this seems like a long drawn out process, when it seems like it should be available in the event. If not, any particular reason why it isn't included?

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to `EmbedEvent` to get all embeddings. The event also has a reference to the current test case.